# How to route API properly?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

API returns 404 on my GET requests.

This is my API:

```
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
class ProductInfo(APIView):
    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        product = models.Product.objects.filter(slug=request)
        s_product = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
        return Response(s_product.data)
```

My router:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'product', rest.ProductInfo, 'product')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

I want my API to accept requsests in the following format:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/catalog/product/slug-of-a-product/
```

and return serialized data.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router expects to get viewsets and not api views. Since this is a classical retrieve api i suggest you use the mixin for it. this is how i would rebuild you code.

```
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
class ProductInfo(RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "slug"
    serializer_class = CitySerializer
```